# QT Installer Framework: Change WizardStyle runtime

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-installer

I am writing QT application for software installer using QT Installer Framework. In config file i specify WizardStyle as "Modern" but in application i am asking user to choose Installer Wizard style which can be Clssic, Aero etc... So if user select Classic when installer is created it should show Classix wizard instead of modern. Is it possible to change the wizard style at runtime? Can scripting help here?

Comment: I cannot think of any situation where I would want to be bothered with selecting a style in an installer - really. So I hope, it cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: This application is to make software installer, where user have option to change the appearance of installer wizard. There are existing installer application there (for example: Actual Installer) who also provide options to change the wizard appearance.

Comment: What is preventing the modification of the config.xml file with the style option selected by the user before issuing he build command?